# How to reload a page only once everytime it gets loaded

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page that is showing previous content even after deleting one of the content. I am working to find the problem but I need a quick fix for this. I'm weak in *JavaScript* so please help me out. I need a *JavaScript* that would reload the page automatically every time the page is visited. Reloading the page does solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it just once, I would use `localStorage`:

```
if (localStorage.getItem('loadedOnce') === 'true') {
    // don't reload page, but clear localStorage value so it'll get reloaded next time
    localStorage.removeItem('loadedOnce');
} else {
    // set the flag and reload the page
    localStorage.setItem('loadedOnce', 'true');
    document.location.reload(true);
}
```

I would really recommend looking into why this is broken, instead of trying to hack around the problem.

**Note:**

This doesn't work in older browsers. See [mdn's compatability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Browser_compatibility) for more information (IE8 does support it however).

Comment: this only works the first time the page is visited.Actually my page has a list of student and delete button.Every time the delete button is clicked request is passed to servlet which deletes the details and redirect it back to the page.So i need it to work every time as user would like to delete student more than once.

Comment: Actually, it will do it every other visit. I thought this was what you wanted. You can always move the `localStorage.removeItem` bit to an event handler, like on the delete button.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **@Omar**'s answer, and similar to **tjameson**'s.  It just uses cookies instead.

```
var int=self.setTimeout(function(){refresh()},1000);
function refresh() {      
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("reloaded") === -1){
    document.cookie += ";reloaded";
    document.location.reload(true);        
  }
  else {
    document.cookie = document.cookie.replace(/;reloaded/g, '');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is nice because it's passed to the server. This would allow the server to send back a cookie to signal a refresh.

Comment: Since this is called *every second*, cookie confirmation dialogs *could* pile up, though, if the browser is set to confirm each cookie...

Comment: @Linus, oh yeah.  I it should be setTimeout instead of setInterval.