# refresh iframe parent page using getElementById

Tags: iframe, get

Is is possible to refresh only once iframe parent page  when iframe contain specified div id ?

I tried this on parent page but didn't work :

```
if document.frames('myiframe').(document.getElementById("iframedivID") !== null) { window.location.href = "mysite.com"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is taking time to load the inner document. So we have to wait till inner document gets loaded and once it is loaded, the inner div can be accessed. Here is my example HTML and javascript code. Due to this, for the first time, you may get **null** in the alert. Hope this helps.

**Test.html**

```
<iframe id="iframedivID" src="Test1.html"></iframe>
```

**Test1.html**

```
<div id='myDiv'>My name is ravindra</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.parent.window.location.href.toString().indexOf("?refresh") == -1){
        window.parent.window.location.href="Test.html?refresh";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: don't work. I tried this with same results, not working even on the same page     if ( $('expectedID')[0] ) { window.top.location = "http://www.site.com" }

Comment: Null alert keep coming over and over again.

Comment: It seems like test.html can't find 'myDiv' in iframe and for this reason doesn't trigger anything, maybe because parent page loads first and iframe 1-2seconds later ?

Comment: Did you saved both HTMLs? in the same folder?

Comment: They are on server on the same domain.

Comment: Saw that. Call `getMyName();` at the end of the page just before `</body>` tag like this. `<script type="text/javascript">getMyName();</script>`. Remove from the top.

Comment: Now it gives me 2 pop up windows.Much better. Please check it. Now please tell me what to do to achieve what I need, which is to refresh parent page only once when loaded iframe content.

Comment: Checked. There is no `div` inside your iframe. Atleast set `id="myDiv"` to your **para** element inside iframe document.

Comment: There is. Please check again under 'Forgot your password' there is 'My name is ravindra ' together with div id.

Comment: Sorry, iframe was IP blocked. Check now.

Comment: Okay. Now, remove `alert(frameDoc.getElementById("myDiv"));` and after `clearTimeout(myNameTimeout);`, write your required statement `window.location.href = "mysite.com";`. Updated my answer too.

Comment: I did it. Result in endless page refresh. You can check.

Comment: I thought you are going to another page. No issues. Have a look at my code now. Added a if condition after `clearTimeout`

Comment: I paste it the modifications. No refresh now.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake one `}` is missing. Updated my answer

Comment: Can you please simulate it on your pc, it takes forever like this :(

Comment: Doesn't work. This problem is killing me, I have on week since I'm stuck. I understand it can be done only with cookies. Maybe you can adjust one of this solution in order to work for my case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549587/how-to-reload-a-page-only-once-everytime-it-gets-loaded   or http://jsfiddle.net/WrPkd/9/

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand what I really need. I need parent page to reload only once after parent page load iframe content. So parent page will load, iframe will load, and iframe will order one refresh to the parent page, which will be triggered only after iframe content loads.

Comment: If you have to refresh parent from iframe then it is much simpler.

Comment: I created two HTML pages. Have a look at these links. In this iframe page will request a refresh to the parent page [Parent Page](http://pastebin.com/hrQP5yCw) and [Iframe Page](http://pastebin.com/08HwgRpj)

Comment: No metter from where I have to do it I just have to refresh parent page once after iframe loads.

Comment: Not at all. I paste it provide it data but it does not refresh parent page once the iframe loads.

Comment: If you can share your desktop, I can help you out.

Comment: I can. just give an email or something to give you teamviewer details.

Comment: Will you please delete site name above ? I don't want people to google and get as result this issues :) Thank you for your time again !

Comment: Done. I deleted the site name.